# Should I learn WPF? Is it a good time investment?

Tags: wpf

This is my first question in here :)

I am a C# developer, not an expert, but still learning and growing. I want to learn WPF so I can create applications that have a nice UI. However I am afraid that, after I spend my time learning it, it is going to go obsolete, you know with windows 8 and metro application and stuff, so my question is:

At this pint of time, would it be a good time investment to learn WPF? or will I be better off learning Metro?

Thanks.

Comment: This isn't a good question for this site. Maybe try http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Exact duplicate of this question though -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/709662/is-wpf-the-future-of-user-interface-design-should-i-learn-it-now

Comment: @NotJarvis: That question is a bit old. Asking if a technology was a good investment 3 years ago is very different than asking the same thing now.

Comment: @Tudor, thanks for clearing that up.That is exactly the point. 

I am not asking if it is good or not, I know it is good. I am asking is it a wise thing to spend time learning it at this point of time with Win8 and Metro coming out? in other wirds, will it be dead soon?

Comment: @omsharp: I doubt it will be dead soon. It's widely used to create rich GUIs and I don't think that metro is meant to superseed WPF. In any case, WPF is known to have a steep learning curve, so unless you need to use it immediately on a project, I suggest you take a more defensive approach and learn enough basics to be able to advance quickly when you will actually need it, but don't go into details too much right now.

Comment: @Tudor, good advice. Will start with the fundementals and take it slow from there. Thank you.